# Hosting MDI .NET Winform in WPF web application

Tags: .net, wpf, mdi

I have a legacy .NET/C# MDI application which needs to be hosted inside a WPF application.  I tried by adding the MDI parent form to the Child of **System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost** but an exception was thrown with the error message:

> $exception
>   {"The child control cannot be a top-level form."}
>   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

and MDI parent's TopLevel attribute must be set to true.

Is MDI WinForm supported with WPF interop?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are still looking for a solution but I had the same problem and solved it by following this example

http://shevaspace.blogspot.nl/2007/02/how-to-host-top-level-hwnds-in-wpf.html

Basically you have write your own HwnDHost control (WindowsFormHost uses that aswell)

Hope it helps people with the same problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.